# Include a date converter function inside of a DateFormatter extension

Tags: swift, watchkit, dateformatter

The extension formats the API date then the converter function converts it to the formatting I like.

The code works, but the call seems verbose. Is this something that can be refactored? Can I combine the two?

It seemed logical to make the `DateFormatter` of the `convertDateFormater` function the `iso8601Full` property. There were no errors, but the attempted call didn't work.

Please post an answer with code so I can mark it correct.

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}

    func convertDateFormater(date: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    }
```

call

```
row.creationDateLabel.setText("\(convertDateFormater(date: DateFormatter.iso8601Full.string(from: value.creationDate)))")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating date formatters inside your method, which can be expensive. You might want to save both inside static’s:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()

    static let dateOnly: DateFormatter = {
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
         formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
         return formatter
    }()

    static func string(iso string: String) -> String {
        let date = DateFormatter.iso8601Full.date(from: string)!
        return  DateFormatter.dateOnly.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
row.creationDateLabel.setText(DateFormatter.string(iso: value.creationDate))
```

This is both more concise and avoids redundant instantiation of formatters.

Personally, rather than using `dateFormat` inside `dateOnly`, I’d use `dateStyle`, so the date string (presumably shown in the UI) is properly localized, but you can do whatever you want.

(By the way, I typed this in on my phone, so I apologize if there are any syntax errors, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.)

---

If `creationDate` is already a `Date` then you don’t need any of that iso-specific stuff. I was basing my answer upon your method that took a `String` as a parameter. If it’s already a `Date` then it’s just:

```
row.creationDateLabel.setText(DateFormatter.dateOnly.string(from: value.creationDate))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'String'` at the label call. I'm not sure, but I don't think it's because my creationDate in my model is of type Date.

Comment: If it’s already a `Date` then you don’t need any of that iso-specific stuff. I was basing my answer upon your method that took a `String` as a parameter. If it’s already a `Date` then see revised answer above.

Comment: I'm using `formatter.dateStyle = .short` like you suggested. It's nice.